# What is Compactness and why is it useful?

Tags: compactness

I would like to gain a better understanding of the notion of compactness (topology).
The wiki definiton defines a compactness of an interval as **closed** and **bounded**.

> In mathematics, specifically general topology, compactness is a
> property that generalizes the notion of a subset of Euclidean space
> being closed (containing all its limit points) and bounded (having all
> its points lie within some fixed distance of each other).

Question 1:
I cannot imagine a subset of the real line that would be closed and unbounded,  therefore in this case I dont see why they add the boundedness requirement,  why not just say compact=closed, and therefore I don't see the use oh the definition of "compact" at least if we stay in 1D (on the real line) ?

Qquestion 2:
is this notion of compactness only usefull in dimensions strictly greater than 1? i.e. dim 2 and above,  and in any case could someone provide a simple understandable example of compact and not compacti possibly in at least 2 different dimensions to be able to compare them?

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is a closed but not bounded subset of $\mathbb R$. (So is $\mathbb R$ itself.)

Comment: Possibly useful: [How does one think in terms of the definition of compactness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951154/how-does-one-think-in-terms-of-the-definition-of-compactness/)

Comment: how can you say that  an interval with and infinity is closed... it is half open obviously since infinity is not reachable?! that doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: See [*The rôle of compactness in analysis*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2309166) by Edwin Hewitt (1960) and [*A pedagogical history of compactness*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.7.619) by Manya Raman-Sundström  (2015; [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4131.pdf)). See also [Raman-Sundström's 1997 M.A. thesis](https://web.archive.org/web/19990224092157/http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~manya/compact/) (the PostScript version has been archived; I got the URL from a [2003 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/01T7BQFuSrU/m/EHCS_9RKXqAJ)).

Comment: @SheppLogan What’s your definition of closed?

Comment: @SheppLogan A set is closed whenever its' complement is open. If you take the interval $(-\infty,0)$ which is the complement of the example above, it is clear that this set is open. Thus it's complement is closed.

Comment: ha I tought a set had to have finite endpoints to be closed. I seems totally absurd to say that a set is closed if one of the limits is "infinity " but well you must be right... I guess it's one of the many "paradoxes" of set theory or and unintuitive terminology

Comment: *the PostScript version has been archived* --- Maybe not all of it. I tried again and only got 9 pages. I didn't check earlier whether it was complete. It might be fully archived in some other internet archive "date options", but I don't have time now to check.

Comment: @SheppLogan: You'll need to adjust your intuition then! Maybe this helps: the interval $[0,\infty)$ is described by the single inequality $0 \le x$. There are no strict inequalities involved, hence it's a closed set. Don't think of the symbol "$\infty$" as being an "endpoint" of the interval – it only symbolizes that there is no upper endpoint. (And by the way, "limits" is not the right word to use for the endpoints of an interval, since that word is used for a different concept already.)

Comment: yes I m sorry I seem to have wrong ideas about these notions of open/closed sets, I didn't take enough care to study the definitions closely and just loosely applied my "intuition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll answer your questions. Then, I will provide an overview of why the definition is useful.

1. An example of a closed but unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ itself. Other examples include $[0, \infty)$, $\{1\} \cup (\infty, 0]$, and many more.
2. Compactness is useful in all dimensions. Examples of compact sets in higher dimensions include a sphere in 3D space (eg $\{(x, y, z) \mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$), a disc in 2D space ($\{(x, y) \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, and many others.

Now, for why the definition is useful.

First, the definition "A compact set is a set which is closed and bounded" is actually *not* the optimal definition. The best definition is:

> Let $X$ be any topological space. $X$ is compact if and only if for any family of open sets $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$, if $X = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$, then there are $i_1, i_2, ..., i_n$ such that $X = U_{i_1} \cup U_{i_2} \cup ... \cup U_{i_n}$. This is often expressed as "Every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover."

Here $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ being a "family of open sets" means that for all $i \in I$, $U_i$ is an open subset of $X$.

A second definition:

> If $X$ is a topological space and $S \subseteq X$, then $S$ is said to be compact if and only if $S$, equipped with the subspace topology, is also compact.

It turns out that

> Theorem (Heine-Borel): A subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if $S$ is both closed and bounded.

However, in other metric spaces, you can have closed and bounded sets which are not compact. The simplest example here is $\mathbb{N}$ equipped with the so-called "discrete metric" - that is, $d(x, y) = 0$ if $x = y$, $1$ otherwise. Under this metric, $\mathbb{N}$ is closed and bounded. However, $\{\{i\}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{N}$ with no finite subcover.

Here's the main theorem about compactness:

> Theorem: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $f : X \to Y$ is continuous. Suppose $X$ is compact. Then $f(X) = \{f(x) \mid x \in X\}$ is a compact subset of $Y$.

This allows us to prove all kinds of nice theorems.

> Extreme Value Theorem: Suppose $X$ is compact and nonempty and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then $f$ achieves a minimum value, and $f$ also achieves a maximum value.

Proof: we see that $f(X)$ is a compact, nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $f(X)$ is closed, bounded, and nonempty. Therefore, $f(X)$ has a minimum element and a maximum element. Thus, $f$ achieves both its minimum and its maximum value.

Going a different direction with compactness, we also have

> Uniform Continuity Theorem: Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space, $Y$ is a metric space, and $f : X \to Y$ is continuous. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

This is the crucial theorem that allows Riemann integration to function.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, if you take the whole real line, it is both closed and open by definition. However it is not bounded and thus not compact.
Regarding the 2nd question, the notion of compactness is useful as a property in general topology that goes beyond $\mathbb{R}^n$. However if we talk only about $\mathbb{R}^n$, then subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact $\iff$ it is closed and bounded (note that this doesn't hold in general). I suggest you read the introductory topology book "Topology without tears" for deeper understanding. You can easily find the pdf for free online. Regarding the example, you can take the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the bound (namely the set of points $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x^2 + y^2 <=1\}$) and this set is compact. However if you exclude the bound (namely the set of points $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x^2 + y^2 <1\}$) then this set is not closed and thus not compact. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks,  I already came across the circle example before,  which i can understand, but regarding boudedness i don't see why we need it... doesn't the notion of closed ir open be sufficient ? I mean for me any closed interval e.g. [a,b] where a ,are real numbers is closed and therefore nessessarily bounded?! if and interval contains infinity or -inf , i learned that is is always open (or half open) ... obviously infinity is not reachable

Comment: Those are not the only closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. You can also have unbounded intervals that are closed. Set is closed $\iff$ it's complement is open by definition. Thus you take any bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and take its complement, it will be closed, but unbounded. For example $(0,1)$ is open, therefore $(-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty)$ is closed.

Comment: By the definition of terms open and closed that you provided, I am assuming you are still in high school? If that is so, my sincere advice is to leave topology for now, as it is too advanced to start learning it first (when talking about advanced math). I'd suggest taking a dive into some linear algebra, or introductory analysis. If you want, I can suggest some really nice books in those areas. Good luck!

Comment: ok I guess I had a wrong def of closed. But don't you think that w.r.t the intuitive defintion of closed as [a,b] and open as ]a,b[, a, b real numbers, then to have an inf is a bit disturbing

Comment: haha no i m not in high school (finished my high school in 2006 ), i m a phd student in computer science but i would like to get more intuition about topology

Comment: I am sorry about that assumption then :D it is just that I learned that as a definition in high school. Take the book that I wrote above, it gives a really nice and begginner friendly introduction to concepts of topology.

Comment: I study machine learning and have leared some  notions of manifolds,  and that's one of the reasons i m interestsd in topology  but i find it to be a very difficult subjet.

Comment: no problem,  I guess i stayed with an "informal" kinda "intuitive " notion of "closedness"